# Minimal matching with sed

Tags: sed

I am making a parser for git, which allows for branch names containing `[` and comments containing both `[]`. So, I need to pull tracking information between the first instance of `[` followed by `]` on the line.

Here's what I tried to use:

```
sed -rn "s/^\*\ [^\[]*\[([^\]]*)\].*$/\1/p";
```

Some of you will know that the `^\*\` matching is for current branch. Then, I try to match everything except `[` before capturing everything before `].` Unfortunately, the matching seems no different than my first clause that was a simple `.*\[(.*)\].*$.` Any commits that contain paired square brackets make my script go bonkers.

I can intentionally break my clause by feeding it:

```
* haha 2b35744 [twodeep: ahead 1] Bad comments contain hashes followed by brackets... bad2bad [].
```

Note that the sed match is between the second pair of square brackets. I want to match `twodeep: ahead 1`, but my clause is returning a null string (matching between the second pair of square brackets). I feel this may be a case for awk.

Comment: Don't put additional information into the comments. Edit your question. Also, assume that your readers do not know how git branch names look like. Just list valid inputs and the results you expect. Whether the inputs you list happen to have any meaning in git is completely besides the point for your question.

Comment: Keep comments civil and constructive please

Comment: Good morning, Jon.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to parse the output of `git branch -vvv` or similar. You may have more luck with Git's "plumbing" commands. If so, you might want to look at, or ask, questions about using Git plumbing commands to produce output similar to that from `git branch` but more amendable to your own purposes (whatever they are). Meanwhile since this is a question about sed, it seems like the [git] tag should be removed...

Comment: That is what I am doing, torek. I am unfamiliar with git plumbing. The tag seemed appropriate to the question, though this is the first question I have ever asked on this site, so I am entirely unfamiliar with its operation.

Comment: I am familiar with some of the plumbing - just not the term. The plumbing will be of little use here, since the sed is used in an rc function that recursively rebases the current branch up to the first remotely tracked branch. Thus, this could be run from any directory. The sed expression I have listed above is used in the first line of the function.

Comment: To get the name of the current branch, use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` (with options if desired). To get information about its upstream you can use `git config`, although it's a bit clumsy. To refer directly to its upstream, just use `@{u}`. I don't know what you mean by "recursively" here since there is at most one upstream configured for any one branch, and that upstream label points only to a single commit; and `git rebase` (with no options) already means "rebase current branch on its upstream". (But none of this is related to sed.)

Comment: I will educate myself with the @{u} option. By recursive, I mean that my function navigates the the bottom local branch (the one that points to a remote), then rebases up the stack to the top branch. If I have L1 > L3 > L8 > R1, where L* are local branches and R1 is a remote branch, calling this function in L1 will navigate to L8, perform a pull rebase, back-up to L3, pull rebase, then return to L1, pull rebase. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does that make sense: no, not really. Branch names are simply labels pointing to commits. They have no hierarchy on their own; they do not nest; they do not depend upon other branch names, with the exception that each local branch name can be configured to have at most *one* "upstream" branch.  Typically the upstream of a branch is a remote-tracking branch, but it is allowed to be another local branch (by setting to `.` the `remote` part of the pair of strings that constitute the branch's upstream setting).

Comment: On further thought, perhaps you mean: L1 has L3 as its upstream, L3 has L8 as its upstream, and L8 has R1 as its upstream? (That's not precisely *nesting*, but you could indeed first rebase L8, then rebase L3, then rebase L1. I wrote some Python code a few years ago to do something similar, but ran down a rathole of special cases. My structure was somewhat different as well.)

Comment: Your further thoughts describe my function, which was fixed today with the addition of some awk. The only way it will break now is by a commit message containing a pair of square brackets on a local branch that doesn't have an upstream. I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ sed -rn 's/^\*[^[]*\[([^]]*).*/\1/p' <<< "* haha 2b35744 [twodeep: ahead 1] Bad comments contain hashes followed by brackets... bad2bad []."
twodeep: ahead 1
```

You should not escape square brackets in character range, just place them at the beginning of the list. So you just have to replace `[^\]]` with `[^]]` and `[^\]]` with `[^]]` in your pattern.

Comment: Greedy matching is still capturing the null string between the second pair of brackets. Oh, and even if the second brackets had something between them, I'd still want to match the first pair.

Comment: Other than the fact that you failed to delimit the right square brace in the captured string, how does that differ from the matching statement that I provided in my question?

Comment: It differs from that you should not escape `[` and `]` in range of characters as you did in `[^\[]` and `[^\]]*`. That's why your output is empty.

Comment: If you don't escape the square brackets, then regex parsing will catch them as special characters. Your "answers" are certainly not.

Comment: You must not escape `[` or `]`  in character list, just place them at the beginning of the list. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11214820/1344961.

Comment: Note than your sed did not return empty content of your `[]`. It just fails because of bad syntax and returns nothing.

Comment: @Kenavoz is correct about placing `[` and `]` within bracket expressions to include them and MHall some tools do allow you to escape them instead but that's not portable/reliable so best just to put them up front as Kenavoz suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ sed 's/[^[]*.\([^]]*\).*/\1/' file
twodeep: ahead 1
```

then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output and a clearer description.

Comment: I'll have to hack on this a bit more today. While I tend to use the -r option of sed, your match appears to work. I'm using this expression to match the tracking part of the active branch in a git repository, as returned by 'git branch -vv.'

Comment: No idea about the git stuff but if you can set that aside and just talk about the text coming into and going out of the command then I'm happy to help. Don't use `-r` to enable EREs with sed, btw, as that's GNU sed specific. Use `-E` instead and it'll work in GNU sed and other variations. In this case neither are necessary since a BRE is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ git branch -vvv | txr gitbranchvvv.txr - | head
NAME                           UPSTREAM            AHEAD   BEHIND MSG
MAKEFRESH                                              0        0 Implementing finalization hooks.
alloca                         master                  0     1195 Detect alloca.
awk-uwr-feature-branch                                 0        0 WIP
chk-manage-vec-branch                                  0        0 Use chk_manage_vec for static slots arrays.
cirqual                                                0        0 WIP
curl                                                   0        0 Curl: WIP
debugger-improvements                                  1        0 WIP
del-indices-branch             master                  8      882 WIP
dict-branch                    master                  0     1224 WIP
```

Code in `gitbranchvvv.txr`:

```
@(collect)
@  (cases)
  @name @hash [@upstream: ahead @ah, behind @bh] @msg
@  (or)
  @name @hash [@upstream: ahead @ah] @msg
@  (or)
  @name @hash [@upstream: behind @bh] @msg
@  (or)
  @name @hash [@upstream] @msg
@  (or)
  @name @hash @msg
@  (bind upstream nil)
@  (end)
@  (maybe)
@    (bind (ah bh) (0 0))
@  (end)
@(end)
@(output)
NAME                           UPSTREAM            AHEAD   BEHIND MSG
@  (repeat)
@{name                      30} @{upstream  16} @{ah -8} @{bh -8} @msg
@  (end)
@(end)
```

The ahead/behind grokking could be condensed. But that would require more effort than the copy and paste; why bother.  Moreover, the code could be harder to understand six months later.

Answer (score -3):

Here's what worked for this application:

```
git branch -vv | sed -rn 's/^\*\ (.*)$/\1/p' | awk -F\[ '{print $2}' | awk -F\] '{print $1}'
```

This matches the active branch, and parses the bit between the first open square bracket and next close square bracket. Branch names are allowed to contain closing square brackets. By itself, sed seems to match the last instance of a character on the line. Using awk will be more reliable than sed alone.

Comment: You don't need sed if you're using awk, it you were going to use awk is certainly wouldn't be like that, and the solutions posted so far do exactly what you said you wanted so it's quite rude to brush those aside and post your own that presumably does something you didn't demonstrate with your sample input/output.